# Is this proof of $x^0=1$ correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, permutations, combinations

We know that,  $$^n P_r = \dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}$$.
 We also know that $^n P_r$ is the number of ways to arrange $n$ objects in $r$ places. Now if repetition is allowed then the number of ways to arrange $n$ objects in $r$ places becomes $n \times n \times \cdots \text{upto } n \text{ terms} = n^r$. For $r \leq 1; \ ^nP_r = n^r$.

So,   $^n P_0= n^0$. Also $ ^n P_0 = \dfrac{n!}{n!}=1$. So $n^0=1$.

> - Is this method correct?

Comment: It looks very peculiar.  What is the motivation for saying "For $r \leq 1; \ ^nP_r = n^r$" ?.

Comment: Yes it is correct, but it only works on $n^0$ for natural numbers $n$. Also please don't just say that $^nP_r$ means something other than it really does. If you have to, invent something new, like $^nW_r$.

Comment: @Henry I put $r=1$ and found it correct but for $r>1$ it waas not so. So I thought it is some mathemaatical _idendity_.

Comment: @Arthur In my [NCERT book](http://www.ncert.nic.in/ncerts/textbook/textbook.htm?kemh1=7-16) they define $^nP_r$ number of ways to arrange $n$ objects in $r$ places. But they defined for r>0 and then applied for r=0 the same definition. I don't know what does $^nP_0$ mean in this way.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your argument can be considered a proof.

As a general reason, $n^0=1$ is a *convention*, not the result of a calculation.

Regarding your concrete argument, it depends on the proof of the formula  $ ^nP_r=n^r $. If you check such proof, you will likely find that for $r=0$ it uses that $n^0=1$.

Comment: For $n \gt 0$, saying $n^0 = 1$ is more than a convention, it is the only sensible value if you want $n^a \times n^b = n^{a+b}$  or $n^a=\exp(a \log_e n)$ to be true for all real $a$ and $b$.  It is $0^0=1$ which is a useful convention

Comment: In my book they say "_Counting permutations is merely counting the number of ways in which some or
all objects at a time are rearranged. Arranging no object at all is the same as leaving
behind all the objects and we know that there is only one way of doing so. Thus, we
can have $^n P_0=1$_" If taking 0 things at a time is **1 way** then for $^1 P_1$ should be selecting 1 thing at a time $+$ 1 thing at 0 times $=$ **2 ways** -- which is wrong.

Comment: @Henry: I fully agree that one needs it to be $1$ in order for theto extend the exponential law. It is still a convention, though.

Comment: @user295895: I don't discuss how reasonable it is to have $ ^nP_0=1$. But when you claim that $ ^nP_0=n^0$, you are doing one of two things: either you are already using that $n^0=1$; or you are saying that the "operation" of multiplying $n$ with itself zero times is $1$. The second one is wishful thinking.